# Interchanging two variable values using pointers in C doesn't work

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm having a problem trying to interchange the values of two variables using a function that executes two different approaches.

The **first approach** is show below:

```c
void interchange_values(int *first_number_pointer, int *second_number_pointer) {
   
    int temporal_variable;

    temporal_variable = *first_number_pointer;
    *first_number_pointer = *second_number_pointer;
    *second_number_pointer = temporal_variable;

};
```

And this works as expected.

But the **second approach** doesn't interchange the values of the two variables.

```c
void interchange_values(int *first_number_pointer, int *second_number_pointer) {
     
    int *temporal_ptr = first_number_pointer;
    first_number_pointer = second_number_pointer;
    second_number_pointer = temporal_ptr;
};
```

Can someone explain me why I'm not interchanging the values of the original variables in the second approach?

Comment: You're only changing the addresses of `first_number_pointer` and `second_number_pointer` in `interchange_values`, not the addresses of the calling function.  For that you'd need a pointer to pointer (e.g. `int **`).  How are you calling `interchange_values`?  It won't work if the caller isn't using pointers.

Comment: It doesn't work for the same reason that it wouldn't work if you just passed integers instead of pointers -- you're just changing the local variables, not the caller's variables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163283/swap-two-values-of-variables for example.

Comment: As a warmup, consider the following code: `void f(int x) { x = 5; } int main(void) { int y = 6; f(y); printf("%d\n", y);`.  Do you understand why the value printed is 6 and not 5?

Comment: you are just juggling pointers in the second one

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are passing the variables for the desired change by reference (via pointer).

The pointers themselves are passed by value which, as others have mentioned, means that their scope is local to that function.

This is why in the C standard library you see functions that accept pointer pointers when there is a need to potentially change not only the base data but also potentially the pointer itself. An example of such a function would be the root of trees included in `search.h`. Any function that could reallocate memory and physically relocate the root in memory accepts a pointer pointer, because you pass the pointer by reference. `tsearch` might need to move the root, so it accepts a pointer by reference, while `twalk` wouldn't ever modify the root so it accepts the pointer by value. [Link to man page for the described tree functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/twalk_r.3.html)

#### Edit: Simple Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void interchange_pointers_by_reference(int ** first, int ** second)
{
    int * tmp_ptr = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp_ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int * foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo));
    int * bar = malloc(sizeof(*bar));
    *foo = 1;
    *bar = 2;
    printf("foo = %d, bar = %d\n", *foo, *bar);
    printf("running function\n");
    interchange_pointers_by_reference(&foo, &bar);
    printf("foo = %d, bar = %d\n", *foo, *bar);
    return 0;
}
```

```bash
scott@scott-G3:~/tmp$ gcc -o example example.c
scott@scott-G3:~/tmp$ ./example 
foo = 1, bar = 2
running function
foo = 2, bar = 1
```

Comment: good feedback, I'll update

Answer (score 0):

For the second approach, you need to pass the pointer to pointer to an integer. You will also need to define pointers to your integer variables (as you will exchange the references and you need objects which will hold the references) It will not exchange values of your integers.

To modify the object passes to the function you need pass the reference to it (pointer).

```
void interchange_values(int **first_number_pointer, int **second_number_pointer) {
   
    int *temporal_variable;

    temporal_variable = *first_number_pointer;
    *first_number_pointer = *second_number_pointer;
    *second_number_pointer = temporal_variable;

};
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5; int b = 10;
    int *pa = &a; int *pb = &b;

    printf("Before: a = %d b = %d\n", a , b);
    printf("Before: *pa = %d *pb = %d\n", *pa , *pb);
    interchange_values(&pa, &pb);
    printf("After:a = %d b = %d\n", a , b);
    printf("After: *pa = %d *pb = %d\n", *pa , *pb);
}
```

Result:

```
Before: a = 5 b = 10
Before: *pa = 5 *pb = 10
After:a = 5 b = 10
After: *pa = 10 *pb = 5
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vfrfzK1r9